# Use of FastLogHook function in immlib?

Tags: python, immunity-debugger

I am a newbie in python programming for Debugging . I wrote a code for using the function FastLogHook() in immlib but i am not able to figure out the exact problem with my code as it is not working :(

**Here is My code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import immlib
from immlib import FastLogHook

DESC = "FastLogHook Basic Demo"

def showresult(imm, a,addr):
if a[0]==addr:
    imm.Log("(0x%08x >> 0x%08x , 0x%08x)%(a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2]) ")
    return "done"

def main(args):
imm = immlib.Debugger()
Name = 'fasty'
fast = imm.getKnowledge( Name )

functionToHook = "msvcrt.strcpy"
functionAddress = imm.getAddress(functionToHook)
imm.log(str(functionAddress) + 'pf')
if fast:
    hook_list = fast.getAllLog()
    imm.log(str(hook_list))
    for a in hook_list:
        ret = showresult( imm, a, functionAddress )
    return"Logged: %d hook hits." % len(hook_list)
imm.pause()
fast = FastLogHook(imm)
fast.logFunction(functionAddress)
fast.logBaseDisplacement('ESP', 0x4)
fast.logBaseDisplacement('ESP', 0x8)
fast.logRegister("ESP")
fast.Hook()
imm.addKnowledge(Name, fast, force_add = 1)

return "Success!!"
```

I am running this code in Immunity Debugger but continuously getting error . I searched , googled but due to the limitation of documentation regarding this I am unable to correct it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also just started to learn more about this topic and managed to write down the following lines of code.

I guess all my comments in the code are good enough as answer. I dont know much more then that anyway.

```
  ' #!/usr/bin/env python

  import immlib
  import struct
  from immlib import STDCALLFastLogHook

  DESC="FastLoogHook"

  def main(args):

        """
                Will hook and run its own assembly code then return to the process
                Usage: First run the script to install hook, then run it again to get results ^^
        """

        imm = immlib.Debugger()
        Name = "hippie"


        # Get stored data on second script run
        fast = imm.getKnowledge(Name)

        if fast:

                # Get a list of all the things we saved
                hook_list = fast.getAllLog()

                # Log result
                imm.log(str(hook_list))

                # unpack list
                (func_addr, (esp1, esp2)) = hook_list[0]

                # Log argument
                imm.log(imm.readString(esp2))

                return "Parsing results done"

        # Find strcpy address   
        strcpy = imm.getAddress("msvcrt.strcpy")

        # Building the hook
        fast = immlib.FastLogHook(imm)

        # This function is required and returns 
        # the address of the original instruction
        fast.logFunction(strcpy)

        # Offset
        fast.logBaseDisplacement("ESP", 4)
        fast.logBaseDisplacement("ESP", 8)

        # Set hook
        fast.Hook()

        # Save data for later use
        imm.addKnowledge(Name, fast, force_add = 1)

        return "FastLogHook installed for strcpy"'
```

Comment: Can u tell me what's wrong with my code ?

Comment: The line with imm.Log in showresult has typos in it. it should be 

imm.log("(0x%08x >> 0x%08x , 0x%08x)"%(a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2]))